# ordering a list formed of char

Tags: c++, list

```
struct nod
{
    char info[21];
    nod* urm;
    nod* ant;
};
nod* p;
nod* u;

void ordonare(nod* p)
{
    nod* o = new nod;
    o = p;
    while (o->urm != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(o->urm->info, o->urm->urm->info) > 0)
        {
            //mut o->urm->urm->info in locul lui o->urm->info
            nod* aux = new nod;
            nod* aux2 = new nod;
            aux -> info = o->urm->info;
            aux2->info = o->urm->urm->info;
            o->urm->info = aux2->info;
            o->urm->urm->info = aux->info;
        }
        else
            o = o -> urm;
    }
    o = p;
}
```

i want to order a char list alphabetical but i get these errors inside of if statement:
**expression must be a modifiable lvalue** for these:

```
aux -> info = o->urm->info;
aux2->info = o->urm->urm->info;
o->urm->info = aux2->info;
o->urm->urm->info = aux->info;
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: You're trying to do an invalid array assignment.  You need to use memcpy, or std::copy.

Comment: "order a char list alphabetical" You want to sort a list of characters like 'b', 'a', 'f'? Or is it more like sorting a list of strings like "Green", "Blue", "Aquamarin"?

Comment: list of characters, i saw i just put = instead of strcpy(), but it's not working nor with strcpy()

Comment: Consider using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C-style strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the assignment operator `=` is not valid for a type of `char[21]`.  You need to copy the contents of `o->urm->info` into `aux->info`.  I like to use `std::copy`, like so.

Instead of writing `aux -> info = o->urm->info;`,

write

`std::copy(o->urm->info, o->urm->info+21, aux->info);`